# Allow the DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabControl have its tabs at the bottom

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am using DevExpress 11.2 within Visual Studio 2010 and I am currently using the DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabControl within my form. I love the way the tabs look; however, I would like the tabs to be located at the bottom of the TabControl rather than the top. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [XtraTabControl.HeaderLocation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_HeaderLocationtopic) property

Also check out the [XtraTabControl.HeaderOrientation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_HeaderOrientationtopic) Property

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I looked everywhere but there! :D

Comment: Guess so. Just googeled for it too :-). But I know it can be hard to find the correct property in such a long list.